# How to align a variable whose sign is absent with a variable whose sign is present while both are inside `\begin{cases}\end{cases}`?

Tags: xetex, positioning, amsmath

I can't seem to align variables properly since one of them leaves its sign behind on alignment.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

% NO ALIGNMENT
$\begin{gathered}
|x|=
    \begin{cases}
    a\medspace{}\text{if \dots}\\
    -a\medspace{}\text{if \dots}
    \end{cases}
\end{gathered}$

% IMPROPER ALIGNMENT
$\begin{gathered}
|x|=
    \begin{cases}
    &a\medspace{}\text{if \dots}\\
    -&a\medspace{}\text{if \dots}
    \end{cases}
\end{gathered}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to avoid using `\phantom` as well as complicated macros.

This is what I'm looking for (from a book):

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why there is a ban on `\phantom` here? It seems like an ideal place to use it. All other options will just require more work-around and more code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated** `standaloneclass` and `aligned` environment

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
| x | =
\left\{
 \begin{aligned}
    &a\quad\text{if \dots}\\
    -&a\quad\text{if \dots}
\end{aligned}
 \right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @bp2017 answer updated

Comment: @bp2017 answer updated using `standalone` class and `aligned` environment

Answer (score 1):

Since you banned `\phantom` ....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\[
    |x|=\left\{
    \begin{array}{rl}
    a &\text{if \dots}\\
    - a &\text{if \dots}
    \end{array} \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

Notes:

1. `standalone' is not for this purpose
2. use [ ] for display math (or the equation environment if numbered)
3. There is nothing wrong with `\phantom`

Comment: Why?  Is this homework?